# Added code fixed opening link in same window.. but toggle function not working

Tags: jquery

Navigation and other links on mobile environment opens on new window. Not sure why its happening. Desktop & ipad version works fine. Used below code to fix this issue on mobile:

```
var a=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
    a[i].onclick=function()
    {
        window.location=this.getAttribute("href");
        return false
    }
}
```

It fixes the issue for navigation and  tag links. But, when i click below code  tag:

```
<a data-ng-click="toggleVisible()"><i class="icon icon-menu"></i></a>
```

getting "Null" error. how to get ride this issue for toggle effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know much of Angular JS ( which you seem to be using), but it looks like the data-ng-click is expecting an integer value to be given( according to [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngClick)). So perhaps returning an integer value from toggleVisible() should do the trick.

Edit:

To exclude the toggle link to be included along with other links, you could add a class to it, lets say "toggleLink" and then exclude that in the jQuery not selector.

Example:
HTML:

```
<a class="toggleLink" data-ng-click="toggleVisible()"><i class="icon icon-menu"></i></a>
```

JS:

```
$("a").not(".toggleLink").each( function()
{
    $(this).click(function()
    {
        window.location= $(this).prop("href");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi John.. my code to open link on same window targets all <a> tag. Because of this <a> tag with toggle function not working and returns null error. Is there a way to protect toggle function from not affecting because of JS code? Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer, check now.

Comment: Thanks John.. Great help from you

Comment: Hi John.. Need your help on this. Your code works fine on android. But, on IOS device it triggered only once. when i came back to previous page and click again (after 2 touch), it opens in new tab. Not sure, why script not working on a single action. Thanks